# Delphi Android download remote PNG to TImage

Tags: android, image, delphi, png, firemonkey

Trying to assign remote PNG file to TImage. I've tried following, it says "Invalid stream format". I have no clue how to download PNG image into Firemonkey styled apps (XE8):

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var qrString: String;
  MS : TMemoryStream;
  Png: TImageMultiResBitmap;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Png := TImageMultiResBitmap.Create(Png);
  try
    IdHTTP1.get('https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=chujisko',MS);
    Ms.Seek(0,soFromBeginning);
    Png.LoadFromStream(MS);
    img1.MultiResBitmap.Assign(Png);

  finally
    FreeAndNil(Png);
    FreeAndNil(MS);
  end;
```

Comment: You are downloading the image ok. But you cannot assign a png or that contents to a TImage is the message. And who did tell you that that url delivers a png? Save contents to file and inspect with an image viewer.

Comment: Indeed your url delivers a png image i see now.

Comment: `Png := TImageMultiResBitmap.Create(Png);` is wrong. You can't specify the `Png` as its own `Owner`.  Use `nil` or `Self` as the Owner instead. Besides, you are loading a single PNG, so you shouldn't really be using `TImageMultiResBitmap` anyway since you are not dealing with multi-resolution images. Try using `img1.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(Ms)` instead and don't use `img1.MultiResBitmap` at all (unless you intend to download multiple PNGs of different resolutions).

Comment: Hey Remy, many thanks for your advice! I converted the TImageMultiResBitmap to TBitmap and it works like a charm! Great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So guys, this seems to be the correct and reliable solution:

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var qrString: String;
    qrDims: integer;
    MS : TMemoryStream;
begin
if Edit1.Text <> '' then begin
  qrDims := Screen.Width - 100;
  qrString := 'http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=' + IntToStr(qrDims) + 'x' + IntToStr(qrDims) + '&cht=qr&chl=' + Edit1.Text;
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP1.get(qrString, MS);
    Ms.Seek(0,soFromBeginning);
    img1.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(MS);
    img1.Bitmap.SaveToFile();
  finally
    FreeAndNil(MS);
  end;
end else begin
  ShowMessage('Please, input a text.');
end;
end;
```

Comment: Why is Png still there? It is not used by img1.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see it. Fixed.