# How to load PNG files from internal network into Android?

Tags: android, image, delphi, http

I have successfully achieved to load images from the web using the `IdHTTP` component from `Delphi` following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359746/delphi-android-download-remote-png-to-timage).

This is how I get the images:

```
procedure TForm9.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var

    qrString: String;
    MS      : TMemoryStream;
begin
    qrString := 'http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2014/04/18/article-2607903-1D2E8FB300000578-90_306x324.jpg';
    MS       := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
        IdHTTP1.Get(qrString, MS);
        MS.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
        Image1.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(MS);
    finally
        FreeAndNil(MS);
    end;

end;
```

However, I need to load my images from my own local network, something like:

`qrString := 'file://192.168.1.4/Dados/A1.jpg';`

and I'm getting back the following message:

> Unknown Protocol.

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't it be the same as a `VCL` application?

Comment: You specified URI scheme of "file". I am not sure idHTTP handles that scheme. If you have a webserver running on your own network then load the images there and use a proper URL

Comment: No, `TIdHTTP` does not handle `file://` urls, only `http://` and `https://` urls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are requesting the file from your local network using an incorrect protocol. Try this: `qrString := 'http://192.168.1.4/Dados/A1.jpg'`.

Alternatively have a look at Picasso, which is an "easy-to-use" library for handling image loading: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Importante note: it must be running on an open webserver. If the local address requests a password for example, this will fail accordingly.

Comment: @Holmes, "open web server" doesn't make any general sense. If `192.168.1.4` would want authentication - you'd end with HTTP 401 error.

Comment: Which `TIdHTTP` would happy handle for you if you configure it to handle authentication.